# Spring MVC generate quoted field name json output

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.0 in my webapplication. I've got recently a problem in my application. I am using `<mvc:annotation-drive/>` tag in my spring-servlet.xml file but due to a requirement I've to remove this and place XML configuration instead.

But now my problem is it generates json output with quoted field names like if I return `Boolean.TRUE` I got `"true"` in the output. I want just true without quotes.

here is my XML configuration

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
    <bean id="pathMatcher" class="net.hrms.web.filters.CaseInsensitivePathMatcher" />

<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"></property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="byteArrayConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jaxbConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean name="byteArrayConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean name="jaxbConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
<bean name="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="pathMatcher" ref="pathMatcher"></property>
</bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
  </bean>
```

any help would be much appreciable.

Comment: Can you please confirm - you were not getting quotes before moving away from `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`, there does not seem anything special in the configuration that could be doing it though

Comment: I am pretty sure when I am using `<mvc:annotation-drive/>` I am not getting quoted fields. But now I am getting quoted fields. All my jquery remote validations are going to fail by this,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [FlexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) plugin, you can create custom output for JSON.  I am sure you can do that in Jackson too, but I have never done it.  There is loads of examples on the FlexJSON site.

Comment: I would look at custom Serializers in Jackson, then, assuming that's the underlying framework you are using.  Or, you can use both, which I have done in a few Spring Roo apps I have done.  An article on custom Jackson serializers can be found here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers"

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you return just the primitive value of `true` (or `Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue()` rather than the wrapped object version of `Boolean.TRUE`?

Comment: it still return me quoted value `"true"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that true and false values are hardcoded in Jackson library (writeBoolean is called even for the boxed booleans):

```
private final static byte[] TRUE_BYTES = { 't', 'r', 'u', 'e' };

@Override
public void writeBoolean(boolean state)
    throws IOException, JsonGenerationException
{
    _verifyValueWrite("write boolean value");
    if ((_outputTail + 5) >= _outputEnd) {
        _flushBuffer();
    }
    byte[] keyword = state ? TRUE_BYTES : FALSE_BYTES;
    int len = keyword.length;
    System.arraycopy(keyword, 0, _outputBuffer, _outputTail, len);
    _outputTail += len;
}
```

so **Jackson will never return double-quoted "true" in field values**(if its behavior is not heavily overriden, for example with codecs).

So please check that [MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html) methods are being invoked, and conversion is not performed somewhere else.

Comment: I am not doing anything or no codecs are being used. I simple remove `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` from my spring-servlet.xml file. and Now I got double quoted true. even all the json responses are escaped. Which I am unable to find that why its happening.

Comment: @ZahidRiaz Please compare the response headers in the resulting http response - are they the same?

Comment: @ZahidRiaz do you have any interceptors or something? It's unlikely however that they will be able to change the output..

Comment: No interceptor. I am telling you I just remove annotation drive tag. and place the configurations mentioned above.

Comment: I thought about spring interceptors because their behavior can be affected by mvc annotation driven annotation(in spring 3 in some cases it will effectively turn them off),  I think that the problem is outside of MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter you can try to serialize returned boolean by  calling its methods directly to check that it doea not add quotes. By the way have you checked what value does MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter  write with its ObjectMapper ?

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior, if you want your boolean values unquoted use a JAXB ContextResolver

Something like this

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;

@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
     private JAXBContext context;
     private Class[] types = {SomeClass.class}; //Add the classes processed by JAXB and exposing boolean properties

     public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
         Map props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         props.put(JSONJAXBContext.JSON_NOTATION, JSONJAXBContext.JSONNotation.MAPPED);
         props.put(JSONJAXBContext.JSON_ROOT_UNWRAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

     java.util.HashSet<String> eprops = new HashSet<String>();
         eprops.add("someBooleanProperty"); //add properties you want unquoted
         props.put(JSONJAXBContext.JSON_NON_STRINGS, eprops);
         this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(types, props);
     }

     public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
         return (types[0].equals(objectType)) ? context : null;
     }
}
```